# How can I make sure I will use the function version of a C standard library function like "getc" instead of the function-like macro version?

Tags: c, function, macros, stdio, getc

I was learning about functions vs function-like macros in C.

Was reading the C Standard and I found this:

> Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also defined as a macro.<sup>185)</sup> The use of `#undef` to remove any macro definition will also ensure that an actual function is referred to.

So according to this, if I want to make sure get will be a function inside my code I have to access to the `<stdio.h>` header file and enclose (I don't know if the function name or the macro name) in parenthesis or `#undef` the macro?

I mean this: `int (getc)(FILE *stream);` (or this? `#define (getc)(...) )`
or this:
`#undef getc`

But all this in the `<stdio.h>` file?

Or is inside my code?

Can you give me an example on how to make sure to use `getc` as a function in C?

Comment: Just curious... Why do you want to "_make sure to use getc() as a function_"?

Comment: I think i could use fgetc instead but i thik is only for knoledge purposes... i would like to undestand C in an advance way

Comment: "So according to this, if i want to make sure get will be a function inside my code i have to access to the stdio.h": No, you just have to write `(getc)(...)` everywhere in your code that you need it. There's nothing about `stdio.h` in your quotation.

Comment: I ask because the first task I was assigned at a job I'd started (long ago) was finding and replacing `fprintf( stdout, "....` with `printf( "...` in a large-ish codebase... The (terminated) former employee I had been hired to replace had imagined he had been writing "_better_" code by using the former syntax. Make of that what you will... (Turning off conventional functionality may be fine for your explorations, but is not something you want to do in the company's code...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in the quoted paragraph, there is a simple way to prevent macro expansion of function-like macros defined in standard library headers: use the identifier not followed by an `(` introducing the argument list, eg: using parentheses around the identifier.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copy stdin to stdout bypassing macro expansion
int main(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = (getc)(stdin)) != EOF) {
        (putc)(c, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can undefine the macros before using the functions in your code. This will ensure that the preprocessor leaves the `getc` and `putc` identifiers unchanged and the compiler will use their function declarations from `<stdio.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copy stdin to stdout preventing macro expansion

#undef getc
#undef putc
#undef fgetc
#undef fputc

int main(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        putc(c, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A simpler approach is to use the functions `fgetc` and `fputc` which are guaranteed to behave as functions even if they may also be implemented as macros for performance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copy stdin to stdout using the functions
int main(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        fputc(c, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In any case, do not attempt to modify the standard headers, which should be read-only on modern systems.

Note also that the macro versions of the standard functions defined in `<stdio.h>` are only allowed to multi-evaluate the stream argument (the one corresponding to the `FILE *`), not the character argument.  Ancient systems where this was not guaranteed do not conform to any of the C Standards, and are completely obsolete. See for example the specification of the `putc` function in the ISO C90 document:

> **7.9.7.8 `The putc` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int putc(int c, FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `putc` function is equivalent to `fputc` except that if it is implemented as a macro, it may evaluate `stream` more than once, so the argument should never be an expression with side effects.

The final word is: don't worry about this and use the macros or the functions without hesitation, but don't pass an expression with side effects as the stream argument, which would be very cumbersome and error prone anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`getc` has not always had such a guarantee. If you need to suppress duplicate argument expansion, use `fgetc` instead. Also, to force the function version of `fgetc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#undef fgetc
```

Comment: Or use `(getc)()` — since the macro must be function-like, wrapping the name in parentheses ensures the use of the function.  See also C11 [§7.1.4 Use of library functions ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p1).

Comment: You say “not always”; you have to have been programming for more than thirty years for that to be true.  The C89/C90 standard mandated the behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Actually that's about right; and I'm pretty sure my oldest compiler is not C90 compliant.